# Error importing matplotlib on MAC OSX Yosemite

Tags: python-3.x, macos, matplotlib

I'm learning to use MAC OS now and have installed python 3.7.9 on it and have run pip commands and installed numpy, matplotlib, jupyter.
Numpy and jupyter work fine but whenever I try to import matplotlib, I get this error.

People on S.O said the installation of the package might be "borked". So i uninstalled and reinstalled it too, but to no avail.

I am unable to make sense of the traceback. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Python 3.7.9 (v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 15 2020, 01:31:08) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib as mpl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib as mpl
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 109, in <module>
    from . import _api, _version, cbook, docstring, rcsetup
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/rcsetup.py", line 27, in <module>
    from matplotlib.colors import Colormap, is_color_like
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py", line 51, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 103, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/libXdmcp.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/.dylibs/libxcb.1.1.0.dylib
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/.dylibs/libXdmcp.6.dylib: cannot load 'libXdmcp.6.dylib' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/.dylibs/libXdmcp.6.dylib: cannot load 'libXdmcp.6.dylib' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)
>>>
```

I have done

```
pip3 install --upgrade PILLOW
pip3 install --upgrade python-dateutil (based off of someone's answer on stackoverflow)
I have ununistalled and reinstalled matplotlib using pip
```

If I run python 2.7(Mac OSX default python installation) in terminal, It imports matplotlib properly. But when I try importing matplotlib in python3, I am getting the above errors.

Comment: Is there a reason to use the framework python?   I'd suggest using conda and condo-forge as the default feed.

Comment: I am used to using regular IDLE on windows. So, I tried the same here. I have never used conda before. I am going to try it on mac.